# Reading a line from a text file into an array of characters in c

Tags: c, arrays, io

I am trying to fill an array from a text file. the array is in a struct which is:

```
struct ISBN
{
    long value;
};
struct Author
{ 
    char authorName[60];
};
struct  Book
{
    char *bookTitle;
    struct Author bookAuthor;
    struct ISBN bookID;
};
```

I tried to write a fillin function which takes the file and struct of type Book, like this:

```
void fillin (FILE * file, struct Book * bk)
{
    bk->bookTitle =(char*) malloc(1000);
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;

    file=fopen("book.txt","r");

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n')
    {
        bk->bookTitle[n++] = (char) c;
    }

    bk->bookTitle[n] = '\0'; 

    fscanf(file,"%s", &bk->bookAuthor.authorName);
    fscanf(file,"%lld",&bk->bookID.value);

    //fscanf(file,"%s", &bk->bookTitle);
}
```

File  book.txt has this data:

```
UNIX Network Programming
W. Richard Stevens
0131411551
```

The problem is, it can not scan arrays and i want to fill bookTitle and autherName arrays from the textfile.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is wrong:

```
fscanf(file,"%s", &bk->bookAuthor.authorName);
```

When you scan a string, the character array is already a pointer, so you don't take the address of it (&). Try:

```
fscanf(file,"%s", bk->bookAuthor.authorName);
```

For safety (in case of long strings), you can use this function:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

Hence:

```
fgets(bk->bookAuthor.authorName, 60, file);
```

If the line is too long, the rest of the string won't be copied in. If you do this, you might have to check if the the string is not yet terminated, and throw away the rest of the characters until the newline. (eg. `while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n');`). The \n character is copied in, so you will have to find and remove it:

```
bk->bookAuthor.authorName[59] = 0; // make sure it is null-terminated
int last = strlen(bk->bookAuthor.authorName)-1;
if (bk->bookAuthor.authorName[last] == '\n') {
    bk->bookAuthor.authorName[last] = 0; // read whole line
}
else ; // terminated early
```

You can also limit the characters with `fscanf`, and read spaces as well, using:

```
char c;
scanf(file, "%60[^\n]%c", bk->bookAuthor.authorName, c);

if (c=='\n') {
    // we read the whole line
} else {
    // terminated early, c is the next character
    //if there are more characters, they are still in the buffer
}
```

To discard the rest of the line, you can do something like

```
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = fgetc(file);
```

Comment: `fscanf(file,"%s", bk->bookAuthor.authorName);` will not scan in `W. Richard Stevens` and 2) `fgets(bk->bookAuthor.authorName, 60, file);` will unnecessarily append the `\n` to the author's name.  Both approaches, as is, do not work to solve OP's post.  Note: strings are never "not yet terminated".  `char` arrays are often not null character terminated.